# I keep getting an infinite do while loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while

I wrote a program that can catch a user input error.

When I try to make my program do a "do over" (with a do while loop) it runs into an error. The program (instead of restarting with the user input through the scanner) will print the `System.out.println`lines from exception catch block over and over.

Below is my code and I really hope that somebody can help me with it.

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int Temp = 0;
    int Rest = 0 ;
    int Works = 1;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    try{

    System.out.println("Bitte geben sie zwei Nummern ein für den ggT.");
    System.out.print("Die erste Nummer: ");
    x = s.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Die zweite Nummer: ");
    y = s.nextInt();

    if (x < y){
        Temp = x;
        x   = y;
        y = Temp;
        }System.out.println("Berechnung des ggT von " +x +" und " +y +".");

        do{
        System.out.println("Rechne " +x +" mod " +y +": ");
        Rest = x % y;
        if (Rest != 0){
            x = y;
            y = Rest;
        }
        }while (Rest !=0);
    System.out.println("Der größte gemeinsame Teiler lautet: " + y);    
    Works=2;    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Sie dürfen nicht durch Null (0) teilen.");
            System.out.println("Sie dürfen keine Dezimalzahlen benutzen.");
            System.out.println("Sie dürfen keine Zeichen benutzen.");
            System.out.println("Versuchen wir es noch einmal :)");
        }
}while(Works==1);
}
```

It will print

```
Bitte geben sie zwei Nummern ein für den ggT.
Die erste Nummer: 
Sie dürfen nicht durch Null (0) teilen.
Sie dürfen keine Dezimalzahlen benutzen.
Sie dürfen keine Zeichen benutzen.
Versuchen wir es noch einmal :)
```

over and over. Instead of waiting for user input.

I hope that the German as well as my code is not to off putting.

Comment: Where is the javascript?

Comment: What kind of input errors are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to advance the Scanner to the next line by calling the nextLine() method on your Scanner s in your catch block. This should clear the input.

```
catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Sie dürfen nicht durch Null (0) teilen.");
        System.out.println("Sie dürfen keine Dezimalzahlen benutzen.");
        System.out.println("Sie dürfen keine Zeichen benutzen.");
        System.out.println("Versuchen wir es noch einmal :)");
        s.nextLine();   // Advance Scanner to the next line
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)
This has fixed my problem I would upvote your answer but am lacking the karma to do so.
So I will just have to say thank you again, this drove me nuts yesterday!